# Pandas merge producing NaN values on 'left' join

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When merging two dataframes, I keep getting 'NaN' values. Attached below are examples of the df's, code, output, and dtypes for each dataframe.

df1

| Customer | Margin Percent |
| --- | --- |
| A | 13.11 |
| B | 23.32 |
| C | 17.03 |
| D | 13.90 |

df2

| Customer | Margin Percent |
| --- | --- |
| A | Nan |
| B | 0.65090 |
| C | 0.20343 |
| D | Nan |

code

```
merged_df = df1.merge(df2,on=["Customer"],how='left')
```

output

| Customer | Margin Percent | Win Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 13.11 | NaN |
| B | 23.32 | NaN |
| C | 17.03 | NaN |
| D | 13.90 | NaN |

df dtypes

[image: df dtypes]

Comment: Can you provide example data from `df1` and `df2`?

Comment: my b, went to re-edit the post right as I posted. lmk if this helps

Comment: Please provide your input as dictionaries: `df1.to_dict()`, `df2.to_dict()`. Ensure that you have no leading/trailing spaces

Comment: Also double check the column names, the provided input, code, and output don't seem to match

Comment: What is your expected result? @snakshak12

Comment: @mozway it was the whitespace. Stripped both columns of white space then merged again. worked perfectly. Thank you!